# Return a subset of List elements whose indices correspond to elements of another List that pass a test

Tags: c#

I have two lists of doubles: Grades and GPA that are guaranteed to have the same number of elements. I want to create a third list of doubles, PassingGrades, to contain only elements from Grades whose indices correspond to the indices of GPA whose elements passes a test.

```
List<double> Grades = new List<double>() { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
List<double> GPA = new List<double>() { 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6, 4.0 };
if (Grades.Count != GPA.Count) { return; }
double threshold = 3.0;
```

This is my long way of getting the 3rd list:

```
List <double> PassingGrades = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < GPA.Count; i++)
{
    if (GPA[i] >= threshold)
    {
        PassingGrades.Add(Grades[i]);
    }
}
```

I've gotten to the point where I can get the indices in one step, and subselect based on the indices in the next step:

```
var indices = GPA.Select((b, i) => b >= threshold ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();
List<double> PassingGrades = Grades.Where((g, i) => indices.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

Is there any way to shorten these to just one step that's not too inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would merge the two lists, that you provided with [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) (*The method merges each element of the first sequence with an element that has the same index in the second sequence*) and after that filter out the elements that satisfy the condition.

```
var Grades = new List<double>() { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
var GPA = new List<double>() { 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6, 4.0 };

var threshold = 3.0;
var passingGrades = Grades.Zip(GPA).Where(_=>_.Item2 >= threshold).Select(_=>_.Item1);
```